# SVG starting a SMIL animation with another element

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I have hit a snag while trying to start a simple SVG animation via a HTML button.

I'm not well-versed in SMIL animation, but according to the recommendation :

> An event value has the following syntax:
>
> Event-value       ::= ( Eventbase-element "." )? Event-symbol 
>                           ( S ("+"|"-") S Clock-value )?    Eventbase-element ::= ID
>
> The eventbase-element must be another element contained in the host
>   document.
>
> If the Eventbase-element term is missing, the event-base element is
>   defined to be the target element of the animation

src : https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#HyperlinkSemantics

I should be able to define a trigger button with an ID that starts the animation with the begin attribute of the animate element. The following example works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Edge

```css
svg {
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
button {
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="rgb(51,51,51)">
    <animate attributeName="fill" from="rgb(89,95,126)" to="rgb(214,166,77)" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="animate.click"/>
   </rect>
</svg>

<button id="animate">animate</button>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't raise any errors so I'm not sure where the problem lies. Maybe it has something to do with Chrome's "SMIL is deprecated / oh, no it's not" thing but chances are I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you for your time, any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se, but there is an article mentioning that :

> Theoretically, the event trigger elements could be other (non-SVG)
>   elements in the same document. In other words, they could be HTML
>    elements in a document with inline SVG. But that doesn’t work
>   in Chrome, which only listens for these events on SVG elements.

src : https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch19-SMIL